# Laravel 5.5 Collection where like

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, laravel-5.5, laravel-collection

i am filtering data using collections. But i need to use like method. I had tried to write like this : `('name', 'LIKE', '%value%')` but it did not work.

Here is my method :

```
protected function filterData(Collection $collection, $transformer) {
    foreach (request()->query() as $query => $value) {
        $attribute = $transformer::originalAttribute($query);

        if (isset($attribute, $value)) {
            $collection = $collection->where($attribute, $value);
        }
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 1st question is whether you really know what you are doing. If you take data from database and then filter it just to take some elements it's definitely not the best way because you can take from database for example 100000 records just to finally have only 2 elements and it will kill your application performance.

But assuming you really want to filter using Support collection, there is no where together with LIKE because you are just filtering an array. If you want to use something similar to like instead of:

```
$collection = $collection->where('name', $value);
```

you can use:

```
$collection = $collection->reject(function($element) use ($value) {
    return mb_strpos($element->name, $value) === false;
});
```

depending on what you really have in collection instead of `$element->name` you might need to use `$element['name']`

Comment: I implemented @MarcinNabialek's solution to do a case-insensitive search on two fields (does "first_name or last_name contain $value?"):  

    `$value = $search_name;  
    $results = $results->reject(function($element) use ($value) {  
        return (stripos($element['first_name'], $value) === false AND stripos($element['last_name'], $value) === false);  
    });`