# how to filter collection in laravel by like

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i want to filter a collection by name like "%something%" in laravel but where like doesn't work in collection
how can i resolve this issue ?
i wrote this method and doesn't work for name filter

```
protected function filterData(Collection $collection, $transformer)
{
    foreach (request()->query() as $query => $value) {
        $attribute = $transformer::originalAttribute($query);
        if (isset($attribute, $value)) {
            if ($attribute == 'name') {
                $collection = $collection->where($attribute,'LIKE' ,"%$value%"); // problem is here
            }
            $collection = $collection->where($attribute, $value);
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419670/7498116

Answer (score 4):

You can filter your collection like this:

```
$collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($attribute) {
            return strpos($item->name, $attribute) !== false;
        });
```

If you get an error saying `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`, just change `$item->name` to `$item['name']`.

Comment: This answer works as intended. As of PHP8, `str_contains`  can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

$collection = $collection->where($attribute,'LIKE' ,"%".$value."%"); // problem is here